# circleci with gcloud sdk UnicodeDecodeError

Tags: python, node.js, gcloud, circleci, google-cloud-sdk

Before asking question, I wanna say that I've looked up every similar questions in stackoverflow, but everything was of no use.

I am experiencing a strange error recently.
I've used CircleCI as CI/CD tool to deploy my service to GCP app engine.

Recently, I realized that nodejs8 is now available for standard app engine. So I switched from flex app engine to standard app engine, and changed my app.yaml,
from

```
env: flex
runtime: nodejs
automatic_scaling:
  min_num_instances: 1
```

to

```
runtime: nodejs8
instance_class: F2
automatic_scaling:
  min_instances: 0
```

I only changed my app.yaml, but this error happens

```
Beginning deployment of service [default]...
ERROR: gcloud crashed (UnicodeDecodeError): 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xeb in position 14: ordinal not in range(128)

If you would like to report this issue, please run the following command:
  gcloud feedback

To check gcloud for common problems, please run the following command:
  gcloud info --run-diagnostics
Exited with code 1
```

I know that this is related to python. But I cannot understand why this error happens as I only changed app.yaml. Is this a bug of gcloud sdk, or CircleCI?

Answer (score 0):

As you may see from the App Engine documentation [1]: This is a beta release of Node.js in the Google App Engine standard environment. This feature might be changed in backward-incompatible ways and is not subject to any SLA or deprecation policy.

Beta releases are not recommended for production, since they might change as described above.

Are you using a folder with extended Unicode characters in the name? If this is the case, try to install/run gcloud into a different directory. Nevertheless, keep in mind that since this is a beta release, incompatible changes may be expected.

[1] https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/nodejs/